# Cordova App location on android phone

Tags: android, cordova, path, location

I am total cordova beginner. I created a sample application that runs on my phone. It is a simple Test Database with 1 Customer Table.  Eventually I will want to import data from a local file.  It might not be necessary to know where my app is located on my phone in order to do the import.  However, where is my app located on the phone? I am using a file browser that shows hidden files, and I can't seem to find the app.  I can run the app as it has an icon on my phone. The name of the app is HTML5_2.  It also is called com.coolappz.html5_2.  But I can't locate it using the file browser on my phone.  Does anybody know what the app path is on the android phone?  Galaxy S5?

This question had been asked before but does not have any answers. Maybe this is just one of those wonders of the world that just works but nobody knows why?

Thanks.
Mike

Comment: What do you think about my comment, @Mike ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the config.xml of phonegap or cordova and read the documentation in [the web](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#Preferences) you can see that in preferences you can pick the android-installLocation and select if internalOnly, auto or preferExternal. If you pick preferExternal, the app be install on the SD. More easy to see the complete rute and write the code.

You can see more of the App install location [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html)

Regards and good code ;)